# customizing gyp and gypi files of chromium source code to add a new file

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am new to chromium source code. I have few doubt regarding chromium source code make files(gyp, gypi).

1) what is the difference between `.gyp` and `.gypi` files?

```
./Source/WebCore/WebCore.gyp/WebCore.gyp
./Source/WebCore/WebCore.gyp/gyp/WebCore.gypi
```

2) How can i check which file is compiling for linux/mac/windows chromium code.
Because when i check the file in `.gyp` file i show that it list almost all the files of webcore for mac/linux/android/ etc.

above doubt is killing me:(

Comment: See also the [GYP documentation](https://gyp.gsrc.io/). It's surprisingly hard to find…a Google build tool on page 2 of Google search?! :)

Answer (score 4):

By convention, included files have the suffix .gypi (gyp include). 
One single .gyp file may include multiple .gypi  files in its  includes field.
like here:

```
  'includes': [
    '../build/win/precompile.gypi',
    '../build/features.gypi',
    '../build/scripts/scripts.gypi',
    '../modules/modules.gypi',
    '../bindings/bindings.gypi',
    'core.gypi',
  ],
```

to find out which code is getting compiled for your platform you can check your code for conditionals like these:

```
    ['OS=="win"', {
      # In generated bindings code: 'switch contains default but no case'.
      # Disable c4267 warnings until we fix size_t to int truncations.
      'msvs_disabled_warnings': [ 4065, 4267 ],

    'include_dirs': [
      '<@(webcore_include_dirs)',
      '<(DEPTH)/gpu',
      '<(angle_path)/include',
    ],
```